# location permission not granted in react native

Tags: react-native

i have small problem  for finding location here is my code

```
export default class  App extends React.Component{
  state = {
        location: null
    };

    findCoordinates = () => {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
                const location = JSON.stringify(position);
                this.setState({ location });
            },
      error => Alert.alert(error.message),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
    );
    };
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.findCoordinates}>
                    <Text style={styles.welcome}>Find My Coords?</Text>
                    <Text>Location: {this.state.location}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
    );
  }
}
```

they show location permission not granted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

first take location permission from user. use this function

```
import { Platform, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

async function requestPermissions() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    Geolocation.requestAuthorization();
    Geolocation.setRNConfiguration({
      skipPermissionRequests: false,
     authorizationLevel: 'whenInUse',
   });
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont know to havr to get permission from user .so please tell have to get the permission

Comment: if i close the app even ask the permission from the user . what will i do for the get permission from the user

Answer (score 8):

The above answer is no longer valid as the `setRNConfiguration`  function is now deprecated.

This is the updated way to get user permission for using location:

```
import { Platform, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

async function requestPermissions() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    const auth = await Geolocation.requestAuthorization("whenInUse");
    if(auth === "granted") {
       // do something if granted...
    }
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      // do something if granted...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me where's this "granted" in if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {}

Answer (score 2):

Please do it like this

```
async function requestPermissions() {
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
  const auth = await Geolocation.requestAuthorization('whenInUse');
  if (auth === 'granted') {
    _getCourts();
  }
}

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
  );
  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    _getCourts();
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

UsmanJ is correct but there is an error.
Here's the fix:

change this line: `if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {`

to : `if ("granted" === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {`

Comment: granted is a variable declared above this if statement which get the current value of permissions, whether the permissions were granted or not. Putting it in quotes makes it a string, making no sense.